# How to remove or else correct networktunnelx64.sys and related BSODs?

Tags: windows-10, vpn, bsod, tunnel

some time ago, I purchased the app PingZapper in order to have low latency in some of my gameplay in my W10 1909. It didn't take much time for me to start experiencing BSODs all pointing out to the same component, "networktunnelx64.sys". Doing some research on the web, I managed to learn that his is a somewhat common problem with PZ which is a pretty outdated app (last compiling 2016). After struggling for some time, I eventually decided to remove PZ (with Revo Uninstaller) to get rid of the PZ's related BSOD. In the meantime, I also updated my W10 to the latest 20H2 October version.

So now I don't PZ on my computer and also I don't have, to my knowledge, any other VPN-kind application installed (I suppose Zoom, Skype, and Discord doesn't count and I had used AnyDesk for months before the BSODs started appearing without a problem). And yet, a couple of minutes ago I got another BSOD pointing out to the exact same networktunnelx64.sys!

Here are the *!analyze -v* results:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.18362.1 AMD64 Copyright
(c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP] Kernel Bitmap Dump File:
Kernel address space is available, User address space may not be
available.

Symbol search path is: srv* Executable search path is:  Windows 10
Kernel Version 18362 MP (16 procs) Free x64 Product: WinNt, suite:
TerminalServer SingleUserTS Built by:
18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202 Machine Name: Kernel base = 0xfffff806`06800000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff806`06c461b0 Debug
session time: Sat Nov  7 17:59:39.504 2020 (UTC - 3:00) System Uptime:
0 days 0:03:40.213 Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
......Page 4050a9 not present in the dump file. Type ".hh dbgerr004"
for details ..........................................................
................................................................ ....
Loading User Symbols PEB is paged out (Peb.Ldr = 0000001e`6cf67018). 
Type ".hh dbgerr001" for details Loading unloaded module list ......
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v 0: kd!analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

UNEXPECTED_KERNEL_MODE_TRAP (7f) This means a trap occurred in kernel
mode, and it's a trap of a kind that the kernel isn't allowed to
have/catch (bound trap) or that is always instant death (double
fault).  The first number in the bugcheck params is the number of the
trap (8 = double fault, etc) Consult an Intel x86 family manual to
learn more about what these traps are. Here is a *portion* of those
codes: If kv shows a taskGate
        use .tss on the part before the colon, then kv. Else if kv shows a trapframe
        use .trap on that value Else
        .trap on the appropriate frame will show where the trap was taken
        (on x86, this will be the ebp that goes with the procedure KiTrap) Endif kb will then show the corrected stack. Arguments: Arg1:
0000000000000008, EXCEPTION_DOUBLE_FAULT Arg2: fffff8060ba7ee70 Arg3:
ffffaa8602c70ff0 Arg4: fffff80606ad29bb

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1


PROCESSES_ANALYSIS: 1

SERVICE_ANALYSIS: 1

STACKHASH_ANALYSIS: 1

TIMELINE_ANALYSIS: 1


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 401

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  System manufacturer

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  System Product Name

SYSTEM_SKU:  SKU

SYSTEM_VERSION:  System Version

BIOS_VENDOR:  American Megatrends Inc.

BIOS_VERSION:  5220

BIOS_DATE:  09/12/2019

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  PRIME X370-PRO

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  Rev X.0x

DUMP_TYPE:  1

BUGCHECK_P1: 8

BUGCHECK_P2: fffff8060ba7ee70

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffaa8602c70ff0

BUGCHECK_P4: fffff80606ad29bb

BUGCHECK_STR:  0x7f_8

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff8060ba7ee70 -- (.trap 0xfffff8060ba7ee70) NOTE: The
trap frame does not contain all registers. Some register values may be
zeroed or incorrect. rax=ffffaa8602c71018 rbx=0000000000000000
rcx=ffffaa8602c70000 rdx=0000000000000000 rsi=0000000000000000
rdi=0000000000000000 rip=fffff80606ad29bb rsp=ffffaa8602c70ff0
rbp=ffffaa8602c710b9  r8=000000000000000e  r9=0000000000000000
r10=ffffaa8602c70000 r11=ffffaa8602c70000 r12=0000000000000000
r13=0000000000000000 r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000 iopl=0 
nv up ei ng nz na po nc nt!MiGenerateAccessViolation+0x1f:
fffff806`06ad29bb e83044d8ff      call    nt!MiDeterminePoolType
(fffff806`06856df0) Resetting default scope

CPU_COUNT: 10

CPU_MHZ: f03

CPU_VENDOR:  AuthenticAMD

CPU_FAMILY: 17

CPU_MODEL: 1

CPU_STEPPING: 1

BLACKBOXBSD: 1 (!blackboxbsd)


BLACKBOXNTFS: 1 (!blackboxntfs)


BLACKBOXWINLOGON: 1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WIN8_DRIVER_FAULT

PROCESS_NAME:  conhost.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  MARTINGBB-1

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  11-09-2020 15:12:50.0666

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.18362.1 amd64fre

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffe584d4340640 -- (.exr 0xffffe584d4340640)
ExceptionAddress: 0000000000000000    ExceptionCode: 00000000  
ExceptionFlags: 00000000 NumberParameters: 0

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff8060680ed5a to fffff806069cb6d6

STACK_OVERFLOW: Stack Limit: ffffaa8602c71000. Use (kF) and
(!stackusage) to investigate stack usage.

STACKUSAGE_FUNCTION: The function at address 0xfffff80604639430 was
blamed for the stack overflow. It is using 8400 bytes of stack.

FOLLOWUP_IP:  networktunnelx64+9430 fffff806`04639430 4889442430     
mov     qword ptr [rsp+30h],rax

STACK_TEXT:   ffffaa86`02c70ff0 fffff806`06a0817a : ffffaa86`02c70000
ffffaa86`02c710b9 00000000`00000000 ffffaa86`02c711e0 :
nt!MiGenerateAccessViolation+0x1f ffffaa86`02c71020 fffff806`0689559f
: 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
ffffaa86`02c70000 : nt!MiSystemFault+0x19dcca ffffaa86`02c71120
fffff806`069d0d5e : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
ffffaa86`02c728b0 00000000`00000000 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x34f
ffffaa86`02c712c0 fffff806`069cb6d6 : 00000000`00000000
00000000`0010000b fffff806`0680ed5a ffffaa86`02c72678 :
nt!KiPageFault+0x35e ffffaa86`02c71458 fffff806`0680ed5a :
ffffaa86`02c72678 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000003
00000000`000004d0 : nt!_chkstk+0x36 ffffaa86`02c71470
fffff806`0699dabf : fffff806`06be4efc ffffaa86`00000001
ffffaa86`02c728b0 ffffaa86`02c77000 : nt!RtlUnwindEx+0xfa
ffffaa86`02c716a0 fffff806`069cbad2 : ffffaa86`02c728b0
ffffaa86`02c71c80 00000000`00000000 00000000`0010001f :
nt!_C_specific_handler+0xef ffffaa86`02c71710 fffff806`0680cca5 :
ffffaa86`02c72678 00000000`00000000 ffffaa86`02c71c80
00007fff`ffff0000 : nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0x12
ffffaa86`02c71740 fffff806`0680b33e : ffffaa86`02c72678
ffffaa86`02c723c0 ffffaa86`02c72678 00000000`00000000 :
nt!RtlDispatchException+0x4a5 ffffaa86`02c71e90 fffff806`069d4c5d :
ffffe584`d4340640 fffff806`068975a6 ffffb3d9`ecf67000
00007ff5`cfecc000 : nt!KiDispatchException+0x16e ffffaa86`02c72540
fffff806`069d0e43 : ffffe584`d4340580 00000000`000000ff
80000000`00000000 ffffce09`7a159258 : nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0x11d
ffffaa86`02c72720 fffff806`069262b3 : ffffb3bf`fae7f660
ffffe584`d4340580 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 :
nt!KiPageFault+0x443 ffffaa86`02c728b0 fffff806`068158e5 :
ffffb3bf`fae7f660 ffffffff`00000018 00000000`00000000
ffffffff`00000420 : nt!MiMakeProtoLeafValid+0xaf ffffaa86`02c72940
fffff806`06dcbd7b : 00007ff5`cfecc000 ffffe584`d71bdba0
ffffb701`00000f00 00000000`00000000 : nt!MiSplitPrivatePage+0x365
ffffaa86`02c72a20 fffff806`06dcb898 : ffffe584`d71bdbc8
00007ff5`cfecbc00 00000000`00000440 00007ff5`cfecbc00 :
nt!MiCopyToCfgBitMap+0x48b ffffaa86`02c72b00 fffff806`06ec9768 :
ffffb3bf`fd249778 00000000`00000000 00007ffa`49301000
fffff806`068e7caf : nt!MiPopulateCfgBitMap+0xbc ffffaa86`02c72bb0
fffff806`06dc9ff0 : ffffe584`d4340580 00000000`00000000
ffffe584`d4340640 fffff806`06868270 : nt!MiMarkPrivateOpenCfgBits+0x30
ffffaa86`02c72bf0 fffff806`06dc9ec7 : ffffe584`d76d4400
fffff806`068341ed 00000000`00000000 fffff806`06812726 :
nt!MiMarkProcessCfgBits+0x44 ffffaa86`02c72c20 fffff806`06de6f4f :
00000000`00000002 ffffaa86`02c72d21 ffffe584`d7486760
ffffaa86`00000000 : nt!MiCommitVadCfgBits+0x16f ffffaa86`02c72ca0
fffff806`06de2416 : ffffaa86`02c72f98 00000000`00000000
ffffaa86`00000006 00000000`00000001 : nt!MiReserveUserMemory+0x42f
ffffaa86`02c72d80 fffff806`06dc2056 : 00007ffa`00000000
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 :
nt!MiAllocateVirtualMemory+0x316 ffffaa86`02c72f10 fffff806`069d4558 :
ffffffff`80004028 ffffe584`d76d4080 00000000`00000000
ffffaa86`02c732d8 : nt!NtAllocateVirtualMemory+0x196 ffffaa86`02c730b0
fffff806`069c6b00 : fffff806`04637b76 00000000`00000000
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x28
ffffaa86`02c732b8 fffff806`04637b76 : 00000000`00000000
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 :
nt!KiServiceLinkage ffffaa86`02c732c0 fffff806`04639430 :
ffffffff`80004028 00000000`00002000 00007ffa`4919f7e0
00000000`00000000 : networktunnelx64+0x7b76 ffffaa86`02c73340
fffff806`04639a1e : ffffffff`80004028 ffffce09`88483db8
00000000`00000001 ffffe584`d4340080 : networktunnelx64+0x9430
ffffaa86`02c75410 fffff806`0463b5ea : ffffffff`80004028
ffffce09`88483db8 00000000`00000010 00000000`00040082 :
networktunnelx64+0x9a1e ffffaa86`02c75440 fffff806`0463b6ad :
ffffffff`80004028 fffff806`163bfe01 00000000`000013c0
ffffe584`d4340080 : networktunnelx64+0xb5ea ffffaa86`02c754d0
fffff806`046312d6 : 00000000`000013c0 00000000`0000000a
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 : networktunnelx64+0xb6ad
ffffaa86`02c75510 fffff806`06dca738 : 00000000`00001034
00000000`000013c0 ffffe584`d446a801 ffffe584`d4340080 :
networktunnelx64+0x12d6 ffffaa86`02c75540 fffff806`06dc83a3 :
ffffffff`00000000 ffffaa86`02c76330 ffffaa86`02c75c01
ffffe584`d94825d0 : nt!PspCallProcessNotifyRoutines+0x254
ffffaa86`02c75610 fffff806`06e8d804 : ffffe584`d59d7080
ffffe584`d4340080 ffffaa86`02c75dd0 ffffaa86`02c75c90 :
nt!PspInsertThread+0x68f ffffaa86`02c75700 fffff806`069d4558 :
00000000`00000000 ffffe584`c8c847a0 ffffce09`7800b040
00000001`02c764e0 : nt!NtCreateUserProcess+0x964 ffffaa86`02c763b0
fffff806`069c6b00 : fffff806`045ead4f 00000000`00000000
00000000`00001034 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x28
ffffaa86`02c765b8 fffff806`045ead4f : 00000000`00000000
00000000`00001034 00000000`00000000 ffffaa86`02c76630 :
nt!KiServiceLinkage ffffaa86`02c765c0 fffff806`045ea921 :
00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 ffffaa86`02c76b80
00007ffa`00000000 : condrv!CdpCreateProcess+0x14f ffffaa86`02c76770
fffff806`045e8ad7 : ffffe584`d6692080 00000000`00000730
ffffe584`c8cf4bc0 00000000`004a3d60 :
condrv!CdpLaunchServerProcess+0x171 ffffaa86`02c76870
fffff806`045eae0d : 00000000`004a3d60 fffff806`045eadb0
ffffe584`d947e750 00000000`00000000 : condrv!CdpServerFastIoctl+0x167
ffffaa86`02c768b0 fffff806`06dd136b : 00000000`00000088
ffffaa86`02c76b00 ffffe584`d6692580 ffffe584`d947e750 :
condrv!CdpFastIoDeviceControl+0x5d ffffaa86`02c76900 fffff806`06dd0c36
: 00007ffa`4915bbd0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001
00000000`00000000 : nt!IopXxxControlFile+0x71b ffffaa86`02c76a20
fffff806`069d4558 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
00000000`00000000 00000000`0012019f : nt!NtDeviceIoControlFile+0x56
ffffaa86`02c76a90 00007ffa`4919c1a4 : 00000000`00000000
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 :
nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x28 00000000`0009e518 00000000`00000000 :
00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000
00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ffa`4919c1a4


STACK_COMMAND:  .trap 0xfffff8060ba7ee70 ; kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  d478b5f79124d0274996d08065a1ffcd79f95f71

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET: 
bc8be9c8d07ac0e2709b19577dd0deb4cccb0999

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  eb0f6c3622795060afedc57caa6d2b9d84beef4f

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  24448948

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  19

SYMBOL_NAME:  networktunnelx64+9430

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

IMAGE_NAME:  networktunnelx64.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  59675c14

MODULE_NAME: networktunnelx64

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  9430

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID: 
0x7f_8_STACK_USAGE_networktunnelx64!unknown_function

BUCKET_ID:  0x7f_8_STACK_USAGE_networktunnelx64!unknown_function

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS: 
0x7f_8_STACK_USAGE_networktunnelx64!unknown_function

TARGET_TIME:  2020-11-07T20:59:39.000Z

OSBUILD:  18362

OSSERVICEPACK:  0

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  unknown_date

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  190318-1202

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME:  20c2

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING: 
km:0x7f_8_stack_usage_networktunnelx64!unknown_function

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {40c7ef30-43b9-8995-cd28-4273c4c8586d}

Followup:     MachineOwner
```

---

So this was a surprise. I imagined that by removing PZ, the BSODs wouldn't happen anymore, and yet they continue. This makes me question if, by installing PZ, I updated some already existing "networktunnelx64.sys" file which is now corrupted and I must restore, but a search for the named file in my C:/ didn't give me anything.

So how may I solve this problem? For now, since Discord was the only "using the internet" app running at the time besides G Chrome and it did show particular animosity when opening with PZ open, I'm going to uninstall it too, but I'm not hopeful this is where the problem lies. So any help will be appreciated.

---

EDIT: As asked by the nice people helping me, I've run SFC weeks ago and found no error. Curiously, recently I got other problems and this time running SFC did point to errors. I would bet, though, there is no correlation. Today I ran DISM and there was no special message indicating correction of any particular problem; it only replied by saying the 'restoration operation was finished with success'.

The great news is that I haven't seen this BSOD anymore for quite some time now (though I'm still getting them for other reasons :(). The only major change regarding this issue was that I uninstalled Discord from my PC and now I'm using its web version in Chrome. I've not yet reinstalled Pingzapper, though, which is the final test to see if this problem was solved. Before that, I'm gonna do a total driver update and PC physical cleanup. Later I'll bring the results.

Comment: BTW, the very name "PingZapper" sounds like they're selling snake oil. Ping is not something in your power to improve. You lose control of ping the instant your communication leaves your building.

Comment: Your BSOD indicates you are running 1903 not 2004.  Is `networktunnelx64.sys` signed by Microsoft or a third-party?  If you suspect system corruption running SFC and DISM should resolve that corruption.  I would be shocked, `networktunnelx64.sys` was actually replaced, which is the reason I asked for information about the file itself.  Please edit your question, and include this vital information, making sure you format it properly for readability.

Comment: @Tetsujin done!

Comment: @Tetsujin PZ works; my gameplay is at best 30ms when I play my game and with PZ, it goes down to 1ms (numbers checked in the game itself). What it does is basically to select an optimized route for the connection between the player and the game's server, the same thing done by multiple other apps.

Comment: @Ramhound regarding W10 version, I don't know where you got the 1903 information, because I'm positive its 20H2 (just checked both the time of the dump file, so I didn't give you a wrong one, and in my System's about). Regarding 3rd party, I'm not sure, but I do have this impression: that PZ installed it. I've already run SFC, but not DISM

Comment: @Momergil - Based on the output you provided "BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release" and
"BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202" neither of those are 20H2.

Comment: @Momergil - Run the appropriate DISM commands and update your question with the output of those commands.

Comment: 1ms ping is impossible. You cannot cheat physics. // Search in the registry for `networktunnelx64.sys`.

Comment: @Ramhound Did as you asked :)

Comment: @DanielB I did search for "networktunnel" and found one folder under HKEY_CURRENT_USER/SOFTWARE with that name containing only one empty REG_SZ and another folder with the same situation under HKEY_USERS/S-1-5-21-2120709598-1073306669-3858685417-1001/SOFTWARE.

Answer (score 0):

Pingzapper has not been updated since 2017 for the last three years,
so can be considered as dead and unsupported.
There are many reports that it causes crashes on Windows 10
versions starting from 2018.

Pingzapper is of doubtful real use and there are also reports that it got
users banned from games.
One explanation for it says that Pingzapper uses the same proxy IP address
for all its users, so that if some other user got banned for whatever
reason then you would also get banned as well since you are using the same
IP address.

I would suggest uninstalling Pingzapper, preferably with an uninstaller such as
Revo. Verify that its installation folder was deleted, usually
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Pingzapper`.

If you are looking to improve your network speed, the best solution
would be to improve your internet connection speed or get a better router.

An uninstaller like Revo wouldn't detect Windows modules that were
patched or replaced. Such trafficking with Windows files could explain
the crashes, if Pingzapper replaced a Windows module by an older version
of three years ago.

To resolve the problem, I see these possibilities:

- Run CMD as Administrator and enter the following commands:

  ```
    DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
    sfc /scannow
  ```
- [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)

Comment: Well, thanks for the suggestions even though they are not exactly an answer to my problem - especially because, as I mentioned on it, I've already uninstalled PZ using Revo and, complementing, all related folders were removed before the mentioned BSOD.

Comment: Revo wouldn't detect Windows modules that were patched or replaced. This would explain the crash, if such a module was replaced by an older version. An inplace upgrade might be required, but you may try first Dism and Sfc.

Comment: See my above addition to the answer.